# Flexbox Layout - Four DIVS + Fullheight DIV

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve this layout with flex-box but I seem to be having some issues with it the black space is just a full height div;

[image]

As you can see this is what it currently looks like;

[image]

***html***

```
<div class="parent-container">
        <div class="cm-text child33">
            Developments must<br/>
            consider the<br/>
            connection of retail<br/>
            with adjacent spaces<br/>
            by focusing on<br/>
            communicating with<br/>
            people as communities<br/>
            contribute in making a<br/>
            sense of place by<br/>
            generating life and<br/>
            animation.
        </div>
        <div class="child33">
            <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_01.jpg)'}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child33">
            <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_02.jpg)'}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child33">
            <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_03.jpg)'}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child33" >
            <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_04.jpg)'}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***CSS***

```
.parent-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.child33 {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50%;
    width: 33.3%;
    max-width: calc(100% * (1/3));
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-flow: nowrap row;
    -o-flex-flow: nowrap row;
    flex-flow: nowrap row;
}
```

I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong I know I need to make the div on the left hand-side full height, but I'm slightly confused on how to approach the layout do I use row and wrap then adjust the width's and max-widths? or do I use columns which wrap? Guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide code that actually works, so we can see the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is you need to use `flex-direction: column;`. I also removed and adjusted some other properties, most notable is setting the height to 100% on the `cm-text`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.cm-text.child33 {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
.child33 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 33.3%;
  max-width: calc(100% * (1/3));
}
.img-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="cm-text child33">
    Developments must<br/>
    consider the<br/>
    connection of retail<br/>
    with adjacent spaces<br/>
    by focusing on<br/>
    communicating with<br/>
    people as communities<br/>
    contribute in making a<br/>
    sense of place by<br/>
    generating life and<br/>
    animation.
  </div>
  <div class="child33">
    <div class="img-wrapper" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/1)'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child33">
    <div class="img-wrapper" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/3)'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child33">
    <div class="img-wrapper" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/2)'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child33" >
    <div class="img-wrapper" style='background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/4)'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After some playing around, I have used this method If i try and reposition the text using the method below, it creates some black space on the html doc due to padding/margin etc.. This method is more usable in my opinion because the column property that you suggested much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should add:

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```

to your `.parent-container` and the blocks will be positioned to the right of the viewport.

```css
.parent-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000;
}

.child33 {
  background-color: royalblue;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 50%;
  width: 33.3%;
  max-width: calc(100% * (1/3));
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex-flow: nowrap row;
  -o-flex-flow: nowrap row;
  flex-flow: nowrap row;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
      <div class="cm-text child33">
        Developments must<br/>
        consider the<br/>
        connection of retail<br/>
        with adjacent spaces<br/>
        by focusing on<br/>
        communicating with<br/>
        people as communities<br/>
        contribute in making a<br/>
        sense of place by<br/>
        generating life and<br/>
        animation.
      </div>
      <div class="child33">
        <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_01.jpg)'}"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="child33">
        <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_02.jpg)'}"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="child33">
        <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_03.jpg)'}"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="child33" >
        <div class="img-wrapper" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/assets/CM_SQUARE_04.jpg)'}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? ... Because I can't figure out how that alone will solve the question, so it would be great if you could post a sample showing how that should look like

Comment: There you go, just added background-color to the `.child-33` elements and borders.

Comment: For me that doesn't look at all like the first image's layout sample in the question, maybe I just misunderstood it ... we'll see soon enough

Comment: I thought the issue was positioning the image divs in the right side of the viewport which `justify-content: flex-end;` solves; perhaps I misunderstood the question

Comment: This is the easiest fix for what I was trying to achieve, I added justify-content: flex-end; to my parent-container class and it moved them to the correct place. I'm not sure how I missed this! Great answer.